# "There was an error parsing the query."

Tags: c#, sql, executescalar

I have the following code to check a user:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string ss = "SElECT * FROM 123 WHERE u=@USERNAME";
        using (SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\123.sdf"))       
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCeCommand selectCommand = new SqlCeCommand(ss, cn);
                cn.Open();

                selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@USERNAME", textBox1.Text);

                int result = (int) selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                if (result > 0)
                    MessageBox.Show("logged in");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("user not found");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                cn.Close();
            }
        }              
    }
```

I get this error when I run it:

[image: Error]

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your SQL statement as below

```
string ss = "SElECT Count(*) FROM [123] WHERE u=@USERNAME";
```

ExecuteScalar will give you the value of first row, first column. if that is not an integer value you will get exception when casting to int. include `Count(*)` in your sql and it will give you the number of records which match your condition and also casting will work. Note that I have added [] for table name too.

Comment: IF i want to do same but with another query like this : https://www.dropbox.com/s/d67yetknugj663i/qup.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

```
string ss = "SElECT * FROM [123] WHERE u=@USERNAME";
```

Comment: @kipo ask one by one question. Venkat answer your question for another problems add new question.

Comment: @kipo Well what do you expect if you execute a query that doesn't return an `int`, and try to cast it to an `int`? Pay attention to what your system is telling you. Fix it by casting to whatever type the query does return.

Comment: @kipo `int result = (int) selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();` which will return single value but you executed `select * from [123]` change it to count(*) as Damith said

Answer (score 0):

`FROM 123` is incorrect. You need the name of a table here.